# How to keep my camera alive when I use Cannon EDSDK in my C++ code?

Tags: c++, edsdk

I think it is essential to send a message to the camera per some minutes ,so I initialize my camera and send message to camera every once in a while  in my main thread , and in the other thread I open the liveview   to process  my other jobs,   but in the liveview thread , it wait time out when sending this message :

```
EdsSetPropertyData(theCamera, kEdsPropID_Evf_Mode, 0, sizeof(evfMode), &evfMode)
```

I never met this when all jobs handled in just one thread， I don't know why it happends like this ,   could someone help me ? Here is some of my code.

my main thread :  (I don't send keepalive message in the thread,but also timeout when starting liveview !)

```
CanonCameraWrapper& wrapper = param->wrapper;
bool setup_ok = wrapper.setup(0);
if (!setup_ok)
{
    wrapper.destroy();
}
wrapper.setDownloadPath("img");
pthread_t camera_thread;
pthread_create(&camera_thread, NULL, camera_thread_func, (void *)(param));
pthread_join(camera_thread, NULL);
```

the other thread

```
void * camera_thread_func(void * arg)
{
    global_param* param = (global_param*)arg;
    CanonCameraWrapper& wrapper = param->wrapper;
    wrapper.beginLiveView();//**//it wait time out here!!!**
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there are two things you have to be aware of. One is this notice in the Canon SDK documentation:

> When creating applications that run under Windows, a COM initialization is required for each thread in order to
>   access a camera from a thread other than the main thread.
>   To create a user thread and access the camera from that thread, be sure to execute CoInitializeEx( NULL,
>   COINIT_APARTMENTTHREADED ) at the start of the thread and CoUnInitialize() at the end.
>   Sample code is shown below. This is the same when controlling EdsVolumeRef or EdsDirectoryItemRef objects
>   from another thread, not just with EdsCameraRef

The other thing is: you cannot access (most of) the SDK at the same time. So if you are using multiple threads you have to be careful about this

Comment: Thanks so much , your answer is very professional !